# latex export uses lstlisting instead of minted, why?

Tags: org-export, latex

I'm running Orgmode 8.2.10 with emacs 24.4 on a Win 7 machine.
I've installed python, pygment and minted and added the following code to my `.emacs` file:

```
(setq org-export-latex-listings 'minted
  org-latex-packages-alist '(("" "minted"))
  org-latex-pdf-process
  '("pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
    "pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"))
```

For some unknown reason, when exporting to latex (and consequently to pdf), the minted pkg is loaded in the preamble of the tex file but in the body of that same tex file pkg `listings` and its corresponding cmds are used. As a result the final pdf shows no formatting of, say, a short python code-block enclosed in `#+BEGIN_SRC` and `#+END_SRC` in the org file.

I know `minted` works because if I manually correct the tex file and recompile it with pdflatex it yields the code block correctly.

Why isn't the latex export of the org-file using the `minted` command/environment in the body of the document?

---

### EDIT 1

I managed somehow to set `minted` not `listings` as the go-to package that handles code blocks enclosed within `#+BEGIN_SRC`and `#+END_SRC` in an *.org file. I did that by using the GUI of emacs not the `.emacs` conf file (will study that file at a later moment). Menu *Org* > *Customize* > *Browse Org Group* then patiently finding the Group `Org Export` > `LaTeX` > `LaTeX Listings` and setting this variable to `minted` instead of leaving it as `listings`. Saved for future sessions, and clicked Apply and Save. I see I can set Options (such as background color of code) under `Org Latex Minted Options`. Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot of minted in exported pdf]

Comment: In org 9.0.5 the variable is `org-latex-listings` - maybe it changed names as far back as 8.2.10, so try that.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. I keep getting the following in the .tex export -- `\lstset{language=Python,label= ,caption= ,numbers=none}
\begin{lstlisting}
print "Jack and Jill went up a hill"
\end{lstlisting}
% Emacs 24.4.1 (Org mode 8.2.10)`

Comment: What did you try? `(setq org-latex-listings 'minted)`

Comment: I wrote in my `.emacs` file the following: `(setq org-latex-listings 'minted
  org-latex-packages-alist '(("" "minted"))
  org-latex-pdf-process
  '("pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
    "pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"))` .  Notice `export` is no more, double parentheses wrap up everything.

Comment: Are you sure the .emacs is read? This is Windows after all. Try `C-h v org-latex-listings RET` and see what the value is. In any case, with a minimal .emacs (with the org-latex-listings version of the setq form above) on my Fedora 24 system and doing `emacs -q -l /path/to/minimal.emacs` I get minted all the way through.

Comment: It  gives this value `org-latex-listings is a variable defined in ```ox-latex.el'.
Its value is t
Original value was nil` with suggestions below on how to include minted. I've therefore added an extra line right at the top of the code in my OP, this one `(setq org-latex-listings 'minted)`  I don't know how to make one long statement about recompiling 2 or 3 times all references with pdflatex.